# Build regular expression visually by interacting with HTML in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have been searching for a .NET based component to build regular expressions visually by interaction with the web page. See the image below for an idea of what I mean ([This software uses a version of what I am looking for](http://www.webextractor.com/pro_use_cases.htm#link_11)).

[image]

I am updating the question to provide more details about the interaction I am referring to.

Quite often we build regular expression on the fly and simply use an online tool to test them. Sometimes we go a bit further and use a tool that assists us with builder the regular expression such as [Build Regex](http://buildregex.com/). The two approaches I described satisfy the technical person.

I am looking for an approach whereby a non-technical person can simply open a web page and with a few click determine what they want to extract from the page. This will generate a regular expression which can then be used to retrieve data from that page.

Comment: Could you further define this "interaction"? Please also take a look at ["What is required for a question to contain “enough information”?"](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/6834)

Comment: @Timmy I have updated the question to provide more details about what I am looking for.

Comment: Thank you. So the tool should generate regular expressions to match the text highlighted by the user and exclude everything else on the webpage?

Comment: Yes it should. The tool can either be specific and only what is selected is extracted or identify the pattern of what is selected and extract those matching elements.